# CSS background syntax not working in Safari and IE8

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, ie8-compatibility-mode

This is my background image syntax:

```
background:url(images/img.jpg) repeat-x scroll left bottom / 100% 100% transparent;
```

I copied this from the web and not sure what the forward slash is meant to be doing there. I am using this to resize the background on responsive layouts. This works perfectly for me in FF, Chrome, Opera, IE10 and IE9 but it does not work in Safari and IE8.

Is there a workaround for Safari and IE8?

Comment: Is this supposed to be in a stylesheet?

Comment: Yes it's in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

background-size doesn't work in IE8 and older version of safari so the background image is not showing that you have 100% 100%.

So just use in your stylesheet like this

```
background:url(images/img.jpg) repeat-x;
```

[check this site](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts)

Comment: I need to use that "100%" because I want the background image to occupy the width of the element. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Nope! you can't do that for older version of safari and ie but if you know you can use jquery to do so...

Answer (score 0):

please set background style only and check all the browsers

```
background:url(images/img.jpg) repeat-x ;
```

if you want full page background use both repeat-x and repeat-y

like:

```
background:url(images/img.jpg) repeat-x repeat-y;
```